From instrumental chemistry, what do we know about concentration vs response behaviour?
There is something that seems to be known that as the concentration increases, % error also increases. In other words, the standard error increases with concentration. But are there analytical guidelines to test this assumption during method development? Or is there is literature about this phenomenon to measure the proportionality of standard deviation to concentration?

There are different types of measurement errors and it is not generally true that measurement error is proportional to analyte concentration. There is an extensive literature on this. Here are a few references that address aspects of your queries: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/410372/247352.

There are so many different types of instrumentation, and so many different analytical techniques, I don't believe that the question has a specific answer that can be authoritatively discussed. My belief would be that, in general, yes as the concentration of a particular analyte increases the absolute error for that analyte increases, but in general the relative error (% error) decreases.

There is a nice paper that addresses your questions but it is in German. However, ChatGPT can translate very well. Baumann's Optische Detektoren in der Flüssigkeitschromatographie (Optical Detectors in Liquid Chromatography) in Chromatographia. A major HPLC company engineer, who developed detectors, told me that it is one of the finest analysis so far, despite its age.

Also, there is a fine book by a leader in this field, Limits of Detection in Chemical Analysis (Chemical Analysis: A Series of Monographs on Analytical Chemistry and Its Applications) https://www.amazon.com/Limits-Detection-Chemical-Analysis-Applications/dp/1119188970

"There is something that seems to be known" is rather vague. Can you cite a reliable source for your statement? That the percent error increases with concentration is certainly not my experience with analytical methods I've used. As MaxW noted, the absolute error does often increase with concentration in some techniques, but percent error tends to decrease.

@Andrew I could have phrased it wrong. The error in my case here is RSD% not bias%
